# How do I fix this warning: "Method not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, warnings, xcode4

I am trying to get rid of some of these warnings from my iPhone application. The one I get the most is when I have a void function and I call it using [self myFunction];. The warning is on the line where I call the function and it says: "Method '-myFunction' not found (return type defaults to 'id')." What do I need to do to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I suggest editing your question to include the code fragment in question.

Comment: Can you please post your method declaration (.h) and call code?

Comment: +1 for trying to fix warnings, this is very good practice! While you are at it, there are several checkboxes in the project settings where you can make the compiler warn for more things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Declare the function in your header file, like so:

```
 -(void)myFunction;
```

or

```
 -(NSString*)myFunction;
 -(id)myFunction;
 -(NSInteger)myFunction;
 -(BOOL)myFunction;
```

etc etc.

This is of more importance than just silencing the compiler: if the return type of a function is not a pointer (`id` or `anything*`), especially when it doesn't have the same size, you can get really odd and hard to find bugs.

E.g. if a function returns a `CGRect` struct, and the compiler assumes `id` (as the warning says), really weird things will happen.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Also, if I am not returning anything and it is just a function, do I use void?

Comment: Strictly speaking the (void) is not needed if you're not returning anything; but IMO you should always write it so your code will be more immediately understood by other reading it.

Comment: @Dave: I don't think you're right there. It's incorrect to not return something from a method that returns `id`, which is what it means when you don't declare a return type.

Comment: We're both correct. :)  The WARNING says the compiler "assumes" the method will return a type of "id".  The compiler assumes that because the method was not declared.  However, *I* was assuming the method @Preston is struggling with returned void, or he would have wrote "myVar = [self myFunction]".  If the method has a return type, you must explicitly say so in the method declaration & definition.  IMO, you should always explicitly declare the return types for improved readability.

Comment: @Dave, @Chuck: I'm afraid Chuck is right. Not only does the compiler assume `id` return type, I even get a "conflicting return types" warning if I declare `-func` and then have an implementation of `-(void)func`. So the default return type is actually id. Consequently, `-func {return nil;}` compiles with no warning.

Answer (score 6):

You need to define that function in your header file (.h) (if it should be visible to other classes), or in your implementation file (.m) if it is private to your class.

For example, if you use a method:

```
-(void)myFunction {
    // do something
}
```

For a "private" function, add this at the top of your .m file; before the `@implementation MyCoolClass` line.

```
@interface MyCoolClass()  // <--- no 'category name' hides methods just for this file
-(void)myFunction;     // <--- add the method here
-(void)myOtherFunction;
-(void)doSomeCoolThingWithThisString:(NSString *)firstName;
@end
```

OR if you want to call the method from other files, add it in your .h file, inside the 'interface' section; after all your properties, and before the @end.

Good luck!

Comment: Sure.  It's common to "hide"  methods via a 'private' category if they're not part of that object's contract with others.  If you see the method not found warning; generally it's one of two issues: 1) that method does not exist for that object; 2) you didn't include the header file.  To clarify, I'm not suggesting you add a declaration for a method you didn't write.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the .h file that contains yours methods

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue pop up for me and it was because I had another header file with the same name in a different sub-directory within the project that I thought I had deleted. This was ultimately making the compiler think the method was not declared in the header because it was looking in the wrong header file.

Answer (score 2):

I decide this problem next:

--file: MyObjectController.h--

```
#import "MyObject.h"

@interface MyObjectController
{
    MyObject * obj;
}
-(void) makeSomething;

@end
```

--file: MyObjectController.mm--

```
#import "MyObjectController.h"

@implementation MyObjectController

-(void) makeSomething {}

@end
```

---file MyObject.h ----

```
@class MyObjectController;

@interface MyObject
{
    MyObjectController * objController;
}
-(void) callMakeSomethingFromObjController;

@end
```

---file MyObject.mm ----

```
#import "MyObject.h"  
#import "MyObjectController.h" //Add this line!!! And compiller will found makeSomething    

@implementation MyObject

-(void) callMakeSomethingFromObjController
{
     [objController makeSomething];//warning was here:instance method '-makeSomething' not found (return type defaults to 'id')  
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have -(void) myFunction; declared in your header file and ALSO ensure that myFunction doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the function is placed before the caller in your .m file!!
I don't whether this is the correct way to do things but it does removed all those warning for me.

And in apple's sample code, I don't see they declare all methods in the h or m file. Can just use it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the object you're using has this function declared also in its header file.

`sky.h`:

```
@interface sky : object {

}

-(void) doSomething:(int)param;

@end
```

`sky.m`:

```
#import "sky.h"
@implementation sky

-(void) doSomething:(int)param

{

    //dosomething usefull 
}
```