# Obj-C Private Method Compiler Warnings

Tags: xcode, methods, private, private-methods

Private methods are a useful construct to keep code organised within class boundaries. An example being the organisation of long winded Quartz 2d instructions in a custom UIView subclass. I am able to include such methods in '.m' files with no declaration in '.h'. A working example from a UIView subclass '.m' file reads:

```
-(void)DoSomethingPrivate {                  //Not declared in interface
    NSLog(@"Does this print a private function?");
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame            //Declared in inherited interface
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self DoSomethingPrivate];           //Error: 'Instance method not found'
    }                                        //... but it works anyway.
    return self;
}
```

My problem is that the compiler generates the warning "Instance method '-DoSomethingPrivate' not found (return type defaults to 'id')" on the line calling the private function. I'm aware from responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293129/how-do-i-fix-this-warning-method-not-found-return-type-defaults-to-id) that I can use a 'no name' interface category to 'hide' private method declarations.

However, when I review Apple sample code [SimpleStocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleStocks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011103), file "[SimpleStockView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleStocks/Listings/SimpleStocks_SimpleStockView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011103-SimpleStocks_SimpleStockView_m-DontLinkElementID_11)", it contains a private function which is neither declared in a no-name category interface, nor does it generate compiler warnings:

```
//Private Function
    - (void)drawRadialGradientInSize:(CGSize)size centeredAt:(CGPoint)center { 
        ... 
    }

//Is called by this function...
    - (UIImage *)patternImageOfSize:(CGSize)size {
        ...
              //The next line doesn't generate any warnings!
        [self drawRadialGradientInSize:size centeredAt:center];
        ...
    }
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can shed any light on how Apple's sample-code private-methods appear to escape compiler checks, so I may avoid having to maintain a 'no-name' category header with all my private methods.

Many thanks.

Comment: Found my own answer after much head scratching... private methods not declared in interface must be physically located above their first use in the implementation for the compiler not to complain.

Comment: Can anyone close this question as I don't have the privileges to? Thx.

Comment: Don't make a separate header for your class extension (which is the official name for what you're calling a "non-name category"); put it at the top of your `.m` file, below your `#import`s and before your `@implementation`. Much easier to maintain! :)